# How do I write a time span in the morning or afternoon Oxford style?

Tags: time, time-words

I wonder if anyone knows how to write a time span in the morning or afternoon Oxford style – I have checked [the Hilary term 2016 version of the Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/public-affairs/style-guide) and I have searched the internet for references to the Oxford Style Guide without any luck.

What I'm wondering, more specifically, is whether I need to repeat *am*/*pm* when the start time and end time are both in the morning or both in the afternoon – that is, which of the following is the correct one, Oxford style:

1. 9am–10am/5pm–6pm
2. 9–10am/5–6pm

Comment: Don't know if this helps : Freshers' Fair 2022 – College Time Slots - Oxford SU - 
TIME. COLLEGE ; 9-10am. The Queen's (MCR) ; 9-10am. Nuffield (MCR & Visiting) ; 9-10am.  See here   https://www.oxfordsu.org/freshers-fair/collegeslots/

Comment: This isn't really 'Oxford style', which only applies to matters related to the University. The time styles shown are pretty normal for the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the style guide you link to is for publications *about* the university (such as the university website).  It's not a house style for academic publications by Oxford scholars.

However it does give the following examples:

> (Good) 2–3pm OR from 2 to 3pm; 9am–5pm OR from 9am to 5pm
> (Bad) from 2-3pm

It is not necessary to repeat am/pm when the start time and end time are both in the morning or both in the afternoon. But you should avoid mixing "from" with an "en-dash"

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I bother you for the page on which you found these examples – I feel so dumb, but I can't seem to find them...

Comment: They are on the shortened summary, page 2. https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/Style%20Guide%20quick%20reference%20A-Z.pdf

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Thank you so much again!